# Is the expectation of X finite, infinite or undefined?

Tags: probability, expected-value

The annual maximum one-day rainfall can be modeled by a random variable X with p.d.f.

\begin{equation}
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{1}{x^2+1}\quad\text{if}\;x\geq0\\
0\quad\quad\quad\text{if}\;x<0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Is the expectation of X finite, infinite or undefined?

From the p.d.f., I know that this is a continuous random variable. Thus, I can use the following formula to determine the expectation:
$$\mathbb{E}(X)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x f(x)dx$$
Evaluating, I get
$$$$$$\mathbb{E}(X)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{2x}{\pi}\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx=\frac{1}{\pi}[\ln(x^2+1)]^\infty_{-\infty}=0$$.

Would this mean that the expectation is finite? What does it mean for an expection to be $0$? I know that expectation is analygous to mean, but to me it doesn't make sense for the average rainfall to be $0$. I think my question is basically how to interpret the concept expectation. Thank you.

Comment: You didn't use the $\text{pdf}$ definition correctly. (What would it mean for a rainfall to be negative ?)

Comment: Short answer: the integrand is asymptotic to $\frac1x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to look out for the fact that $f(x) =0$ for $x<0$. That means that
$$\mathbb{E}[X] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf(x) \ dx = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{2x}{\pi (x^2+1)}$$
Now you figure out that this integral is not finite, so the expectation of the given distribution is not finite.

Actually the integral you calculated is also undefined as you have a $\infty - \infty$ situation that is not defined. The integral
$$\int_{-a}^a \frac{2x}{\pi (1+x^2)}$$
exists for every $a >0$, but that does not mean that the integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ also exists. It is just the so-called "Cauchy principal value" that exists in this case, but not the improper integral.